# Создать свой командный процессор

Tags: c++, c, bash

Здравствуйте.

Требуется создать оболочку, командный процессор, аналог Bash.

Хочу получить опыт. Выполнить разработку проекта от и до, пройти все этапы. Чтобы в итоге, пользователь мог скачать программу из репозитория, установить и пользоваться.

Оболочка под Линукс. Выбираю язык Си или С++. Склоняюсь больше к С++, так как на нём больше опыт программирования, решения разного рода задач от студенческих задач, до написания 2Д игры. Да и ООП можно задействовать, есть задумки.

Первый этап. Не понятно, как сделать саму оболочку. Использовать вызов терминала (консоль) и передавать результаты в него. Или лучше сделать свою оболочку на GTK+.

Нужно в итоге получить тот же самый результат работы как с терминалом и Bash. Открыл программу, ввел команду показать папки, создать папку и команды выполняются. Написал на своём внутреннем языке-скрипте команды, вызвал название скрипта и все действия выполнились.

Comment: Лучше не писать свою консоль на GTK+, а написать консольную программу. Во-первых, проще, во-вторых, удобнее пользователю.

Comment: Значит для выполнения команд, нужно будет сначала запустить терминал, вызвать моё консольную программу и в ней уже выполнять команды, верно? Этот процесс понятен.

А как сделать так, чтобы это был как терминал или shell? Запускаешь программу терминал, в ней сразу указываешь cp/chmod/mkdir и они сразу выполняются. А если указал ./script то выполняется твой скрипт на Bash. Как тоже самое сделать, убрав этап запуска чужой внешней программы в виде терминала?

Comment: @Infum: Во-первых, написать свою оболочку консоли сложно, вам придётся реализовывать довольно сложную логику, причём при наличии готовых решений. То есть, очередной велосипед. Ещё сложнее написать свой shell. Во-вторых, написать скрипт, который запустит терминал и в нём вашу программу — вопрос одной минуты.

Comment: @avp, рекомендую в виде ответа оформить.

Comment: @VladD: Велосипедов множество и их всё равно создают. У меня специфическая задача, которую я хочу сам сделать. В общем, это отдельная тема.

Comment: Нашёлся целый туториал по написанию шела: [Tutorial - Write a Shell in C](https://brennan.io/2015/01/16/write-a-shell-in-c/?utm_content=buffercbd8b&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

посмотрите как сделаны готовые проекты на гитхабе, из тех что попроще - xv6.

> Хочу получить опыт. <....> Оболочка под Линукс <...> Склоняюсь больше к С++...

Присоединитесь и покопайтесь в коде проекта fish, она на плюсах, под линух, хорошо работает, свежая а потому относительно простая и есть куда развивать.

Comment: @vladimir vologdin, любопытно. А напишите несколько слов поподробней, что это за fish 

(для чего нужна и т.д. Да и ссылочку приведите, не через гугл же искать, чтобы глянуть).

Comment: @vladimir vologdin, нашел, почитал доку. 

Неплохо выглядит работа с массивами (в другом месте они же (?) lists), подстановка значений переменных и stdout команд.

К сожалению не увидел таких же возможностей для манипуляций со строками. 

Так и не понял можно ли делать IO redirect (`<`, `>`) и pipes с функциями.

...

А Вы участник проекта?

Если да, то в каком направлении команда думает его развивать

(например, чтобы заинтересовать меня реально попробовать fish)?

Comment: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/ - не смущайтесь большого количества фаилов, там в среднем по 20-30 строк кода. В принципе по часу в день за месяц можно более-менее подробно ознакомиться с внутренним устройством.

Если стоит линукс, то вероятно сам fish есть в репозиторияx, можно установить и попробывать.
для дебиан:
    $aptitude show fish
friendly interactive shell
Fish is a shell geared towards interactive use.  Its features are focused on user friendliness and discoverability.  The language syntax is simple but incompatible with other shell languages.
Сайт: http://fishshell.com/

Comment: пока собирал ссылки, вы коммент написали.
Нет, не участник, пользователь. Со строками и скриптами там все в порядке (другое дело, что с точки зрения администрирования скрипты следует писать универсальные, т.е. для sh или bash - т.к. есть в любом дистрибутиве и на любой системе за редким исключением)

Comment: @vladimir vologdin, спасибо. Говорите со строками все в порядке? Значит я просто не нашел. 

Т.е. можно (аналогично работе с массивом), скажем, заменить 3 символа в середине строки на 2 других?

То, что fish (по крайней мере пока) чисто интерактивный инструмент для локального (и личного) применения -- я уже понял.

К сожалению, он не произвел на меня такого же впечатления, как в свое время лекция Остераута о своем tcl на Дона Лайбса (автор expect), видимо уже возрастное...

Так что, пока я его реально пробовать не думаю (хотя, может сорсы и посмотрю на досуге).

--

А Вы в нем реально сидите?

Comment: >А Вы в нем реально сидите?
оболочка по умолчанию.
>Т.е. можно (аналогично работе с массивом), скажем, заменить 3 символа в середине строки на 2 других?
мне просто не приходилось делать сложные вещи с fish-ем (как впрочем и с bash или sh). Для парсинга строк есть удобный пайтон с его регекспами. Кстати, у последнего тоже есть шелл, но вероятно на питоне написанный. fish c tcl-ом сравнить не могу так как не пользовался последним

Answer (score 3):

[[@Infum](/users/20319/infum)](/users/20319/infum), в основе всех подобных систем лежит так называемый [REPL](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL) цикл (покопавшись в сети найдете много инфы на эту тему).

--

А вот Ваша фраза:

```
  Запускаешь программу терминал, в ней сразу указываешь cp/chmod/mkdir и они сразу выполняются
```

наводит на мысль, что Вы пока еще не очень хорошо понимаете, что именно происходит на самом деле.

Запуская терминал, Вы сразу запускаете в нем shell, который и запускает  все команды (ls, cp, mkdir ...).

Как это делать -- почитайте man fork и man execl (а лучше сначела какую-нибудь книжку, типа "системное программирование *nix").

Терминал (окошко, в котором Вы набираете буквы и видите результаты) -- это "другая песня".

Это графическая программа, которая передает вводимые символы запущенной (обычно неявно) в ней прграмме (шеллу) и изображающая ее вывод на экране. При этом она обычно моделирует (в смысле интерпретации управляющих кодов) поведение известных "железных" терминалов.

Как правильно передавать-принимать -- отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ и рекомендации. Я немного не корректно выразил мысль про запуск команд. Понимаю даже как примерно устроены все эти команды.

Одна из задач, которую хочется решить, это разработать оболочку для написания скриптов для простых Linux программ и программирование микроконтоллеров (Вместо тяжеловесных IDE с урезанным Си).